# What bookmarklet converts Google search into YouTube search?

Tags: youtube, google-search, bookmarklet

You used to be able to perform a search in Google and then press the YouTube button to convert the search to a YouTube search. However, now (presumably for equity reasons) they have a "video" button which performs the search across many video sites.

So I'd like to have a bookmarklet that takes the keywords in an existing Google search and searches YouTube using the same keywords. I have one for Google Scholar. I'd like to have an equivalent one for YouTube.

What bookmarklet converts Google search into YouTube search?

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is ancient now but it hasn't been solved correctly, i.e. in the form of:

> a bookmarklet that takes the keywords in an existing Google search and searches YouTube using the same keywords

I was looking for the exact same thing as OP and this post was pretty much the only relevant Google search result, so I made a bookmarklet myself for this purpose.

Here's the code:

```
(function() {
    var paramString = location.hash || location.search,
        params = {},
        query;

    paramString.slice(1).split('&').forEach(function(param) {
        param = param.split('=');
        params[param[0]] = param[1];
    });

    query = params.q || params.as_q;
    location = '//www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + query;
}());
```

And here's the bookmarklet-friendly version:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20o,c=location.hash||location.search,a={};c.slice(1).split(%22%26%22).forEach(function(o){o=o.split(%22=%22),a[o[0]]=o[1]}),o=a.q||a.as_q,location=%22//www.youtube.com/results%3Fsearch_query=%22+o})();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Chrome, you can configure a custom search engine so that you can get results by directly typing your search keyword in the address bar or "omnibox". The steps are simple and described in the [section *See details on setting up a search engine* in the article "Manage search engines" of the Chrome documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95653?hl=en).

- Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
- Select Settings and find the "Search" section.
- Click Manage search engines.
- To add a search engine, scroll to the bottom of the dialog and fill out the fields to set up the search engine.
- In the first text box of the row, type *YouTube*
- In the second  text box specify a keyword by which you want to refer to the custom search engine, lets say *YT*
- In the third box, paste this - *http://www.google.com/custom?q=site%3Ayoutube.com+%s&btnG=Search* (in the URL *site%3Ayoutube.com* represents the *site:* operator which restricts the search scope to just YouTube.com)
  [image]

Now your custom search engine is ready. When you wish to search for a video on YouTube, type YT in the Chrome address bar and then press space or tab followed by the keywords you want to search by.

An even simpler way to implement the above steps is to go to the YouTube site, right-click within the search box and select *Add As Search Engine...*.

[image]

In the dialog box that appears, the text boxes will be pre-filled.

[image]

You can choose to change the value for the Keyword box to YT instead of youtube.com

Update about bookmarklet: You can use this snippet for the bookmarklet
you can use this code snippet:

```
javascript:var k=prompt('Keywords');window.location='http://www.google.com/custom?btnG=Search&q=site%3Ayoutube.com+%20'+k;
```

or grab the [bookmarklet link](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2013/11/a-simpler-way-to-configure-custom.html#bkmrklt) from here

Comment: +1 for a useful suggestion that may help some people. However I'm specifically looking for a bookmraklet, or at least a single button that converts a google search into a YouTube search.

Comment: @jeromy-anglim I've updated my answer with the link & code for the bookmarklet